# i have sqlite database in that i inserted a row but it will show forceclose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

this code containg sqlite database in that i havae one inser button and delete button when we click insert button i want  inserted one row in my table athe code not any errors not it showing error but in emulator it will show force close error

package com.android.sample;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
//    public static final String KEY_FNAME = "fname";
//    public static final String KEY_PID = "pid";
//    public static final String KEY_SEX = "sex";
//  
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqldb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Mytable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Mytable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+ "name text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db; 

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String name) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
      //  initialValues.put(KEY_ROWID, _id);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
//        initialValues.put(KEY_FNAME, fname);
//        initialValues.put(KEY_PID,pid);
//        initialValues.put(KEY_SEX,sex);
//        
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }






    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_NAME,
                }, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_NAME,
                     }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long _id, String name, 
    String fname, String pid,String sex) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_ROWID, _id);
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);

        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID , null) > 0;
    }
}

SQlit data example


package com.android.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class sqlieDataExample extends Activity {
    Button insert_but,cancle_but,retrive_but;
    String str;
    TextView tv;
    DBAdapter db;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sqliteexample);
            Intent in=getIntent();
            Bundle b=in.getExtras();
            if(b!=null)
            {
                 str=b.getString("mudata");
            }
            db=new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            db.open();
            insert_but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insert_but);
            cancle_but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancle_but);
            retrive_but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.retrive_but);
            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(str);

            insert_but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.insertTitle(str);


                }});
            cancle_but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //db.deleteTitle(2);
                    Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),contactssample.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //finish();

                }});
            retrive_but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Cursor cr=db.getAllTitles();
                    cr.moveToFirst();
                    do
                    {
                        System.out.println("vinod "+cr.getString(1));
                    }while(cr.moveToNext());


                }});

}
}
```

Comment: There should be some error logged in logcat. It is strange that without any log app is forceclosed.

Comment: Please post the logcat error... as it may help understand the problem better ... it may be possible that your "str" variable is null and it may throw exception as you have mentioned text not null while creating table

Answer (score 0):

instead of  passing application context

```
 db=new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

try

```
  db=new DBAdapter(sqlieDataExample.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `str` before `db.insertTitle(str);`, may be its empty or `NULL`.